# Continue code when awaited PushModalAsync Page is closed Xamarin.Forms

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin.forms, async-await, modal-dialog

I have a method like this:

```
public async Task BtnLoad_OnClick()
    {

        MediaPage galleryPage = new MediaPage();
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(galleryPage);

        try
        {
            //some logic here;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //
        }
    }
```

My intention was to open MediaPage() and wait until it is closed before the try{}catch{} follows.

As of now, as soon as the MediaPage opens, the try{}catch{} is executed straight away, and this is not what I intend.

How can I wait until the PushModalAsync(galleryPage) is closed?

Answer (score 0):

OK.

I found the solution:

```
galleryPage.Disappearing += (sender2, e2) => {//after closing logic here.}
```